# Sitecore - how do I set a default language for a particular item?

Tags: sitecore, version, sitecore8

I have a multi-language site and I'm trying to create a new Spanish page. This page has no English version. When I try to view it I'm getting an error because it has not English version. There are other items on my site that were created by previous developers that only have a Spanish version and work fine, what am I missing? Is there a setting in Sitecore to specify which language version to return?

Comment: if you are looking for spanish page it does not need to have english version, u might be missing some content on the page or placeholders/datasources are not set correctly? provide the error message so we can look into what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you could be interested in the LanguageFallback functionality. You can configure that Spanish is a fallback language in case if the version in English doesn't exist.
Here are the links to the related articles: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/language_fallback/language_fallback

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/language_fallback/setting_up/enable_and_set_up_language_fallback